# Meaning of the underscore in WaitCallback

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, linq

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((_) => { MyMethod(param1, Param2); }), null);
```

Could you please explain the meaning of underscore (_) in the WaitCallBack constructor?

Comment: This is a discard parameter. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/lambda-discard-parameters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The unserscore is actually the argument to the anonymous method.  It's a common technique if a lambda expression that takes an input parameter is needed, but the input parameter is not actually used.

It's exactly equivalent to:

```
new WaitCallback(x => { MyMethod(param1, Param2); })
```

Answer (score 3):

**Underscore is a valid C# identifier name**, and usually used with lambda expression to specify a parameter for the expression which will be ignored

You may see: [Nice C# idiom for parameterless lambdas](http://charlieflowers.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/nice-c-idiom-for-parameterless-lambdas/)